# How in xCode can you store block methods in a variable?

Tags: xcode, block, private, var

I have a method like so:

```
- (void)showPermissionRequestsWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
    completionHandler();
}
```

I like to store the completionHandler in a private var so I can dispatch it at the proper time. Does anyone know how to accomplish such?

---

I now have:

```
typedef void (^VoidBlockType)();

@interface CMPermissionCenter : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    @private
    VoidBlockType   _didShowPermissionRequestsBlock; 
}

- (void)showPermissionRequestsWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
{
        _didShowPermissionRequestsBlock = [completionHandler retain];
        [self doSomeWork];
}

- (void)doSomeWork
{
        _didShowPermissionRequestsBlock();
        [_didShowPermissionRequestsBlock release];
        _didShowPermissionRequestsBlock = nil;
}
```

But something tells me this is not the correct way.

Comment: any solution to this question found?